# Laravel Relationship/JOIN not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I might be missing the point of Relationships with Eloquent with this one but, if I was doing it with raw SQL, this would be my query;

```
SELECT [I have lots of columns I won't list them all here] 
FROM payments as t1 
LEFT JOIN selected_postcodes_34894839483_1 as t2 ON t1.`Vendor ZIP` = t2.postcode
```

selected_postcodes_xxxxxxx_x just holds a list of postcodes.

My Controller is like this;

```
$temp_table_data = new TempTable;
$payments = $temp_table_data
    ->setTempTable("selected_postcodes_{$timestamp_string}_{$userid}")
    ->payment()->get()->toArray();
```

At the time, I thought the ->payment() part of that query would maybe return all the related payments data. I don't think that's right, but I don't know what else to try.

I have my models like this;

```
class Payment extends Model {
  public function tempTable()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TempTable', 'postcode', 'Vendor ZIP');
  }
```

And;

```
class TempTable extends Model {
  public function setTempTable($selected_tablename){
    $this->table = $selected_tablename;
    return $this;
   }

  public function getTable(){
     if (isset($this->table))
       $this->setTempTable($this->table);
       return $this->table;
    }

  public function payment(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Payment', 'Vendor ZIP', 'postcode');
  }
}
```

I have tried just seeing if the TempTable model works in it's own right - forgetting about the join/relationship;

```
$data = $temp_table_data->setTempTable("selected_postcodes_{$timestamp_string}_{$userid}")->get()->toArray();
```

That **does** work. I get a proper collection returned. I have also tried taking out the space in `Vendor ZIP` and that did nothing to help.

**---UPDATE---**

This is the error I get;

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payments.Vendor ZIP' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: select * from `payments` where `payments`.`Vendor ZIP` is null and `payments`.`Vendor ZIP` is not null)
```

**---SECOND UPDATE---**

```
CREATE TABLE `selected_postcodes_1431076067_1` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`postcode` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1581 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm not the owner of this table - so I probably can't change the field names to remove spaces (unless necessary);

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Input RAC` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Input LPC Code` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Input UIN Code` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Fiscal Year` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Contract Number` varchar(14) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Foreign Ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Valued or Running` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Recoverable Ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Contract Title` varchar(93) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Contract Start Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Current Contract End Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`IPT or Team Short Title` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`BLB No DEFFORM 57` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Senior Comm Officer Title` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P2P Contract Exemption` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Current Total Contract Value` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Code` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`Current Vendor Name` varchar(39) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Site Code` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Reg No` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
`NCage` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`P2P Ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SME Ind` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW1 - Concept` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW2 - Assessment` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW3 - Demonstration` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW4 - Manufacture` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW5 - In-Service` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW6 - Disposal` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW7 - Project Support` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW8 - Ext Assistance` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW9 - Hire/Lease` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW10 - MAC` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW11 - Provision of Services` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW12 - Defence Estates` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TOW13 - Provision of Utilities` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Ext Assist Cat` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SIC Code PFI` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`SIC` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`SIC Version` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`SIC Group Cleansed Flag` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SIC Group Uncleansed` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`SIC Group Cleansed` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`Type01- Int Collab/MOU` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Type02 - Partnering` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Type03 - PFI` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Type04 - Enabling Pan Govt` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Type05 - Framework Tech Services` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Type06 - Enabling MOD Only` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EndCust1 - Navy` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EndCust2 - MOD` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EndCust3 - Army` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EndCust4 - OGD/Agency` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EndCust5 - Air Force` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EndCust6 - Other Govts` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov1 - Int Prop Rights` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov2 - Defcon 176A` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov3 - Interim Payments` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov4 - Liquidated Damages` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov5 - Defform 47SC` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov6 - Defcon 528` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov7 - Earned Value Mgmt` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov8 - Express Guarantee` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov9 - Cttr Log Support` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prov10 - Gain Share` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Competitive Ind` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`VOP Indicator` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`NCP1 - DEFCON 127` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`NCP2 - DEFCON 643` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`NCP3 - DEFCON 648` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`NCP4 - DEFCON 653` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`NCP5 - Govt Prof Formula Rates Apply` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`NCP6 - Target Cost Arrangement` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEA1 - Being Negotiated` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEA2 - Anticipated But Deferred` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEA3 - Concluded` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEA4 - Not Anticipated` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEA5 - N/A` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEARef1 - Standard Agreement` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEARef2 - Omnibus Agreement` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEARef3 - Master Agreement` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEARef4 - International MOU` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEARef5 - Subcontract CEA 1` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEARef6 - Subcontract CEA 2` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CEARef7 - Subcontract CEA 3` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Loan Item1 - CWI` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Loan Item2 - CWA` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Loan Item3 - CSI` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Loan Item4 - CEI` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Loan Item5 - DEFCON 23` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Loan Item6 - DEFCON 694` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SCA1` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SCA2` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SCA3` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`SCA Value` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req Ind` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 1 - Exempt` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 2 – Non-exempt` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 5 – PSC Non-Schedule 5` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 6 – PSC Schedule 5` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 7 – PWC` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 8 – PSvC` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 9 – Abs of tender` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 10 – R&D (Supply Cont)` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 11 – Extreme urgency` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 12 – Prop/Tech` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 13 – Works/Services` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 14 – Supplies/Wks/Svcs added` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req 15 – Cat B Service` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Req Advert` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`EC Requirements Below Threshold` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Sustainable Procurement Pre` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Sustainable Procurement Post` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CITS Applicable` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CITS Type Sub CTR` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Contract Transparency Indicator` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`FOI Absolute Exemption` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`FOI Exemption` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Military Sensitive Technical Information` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Warlike Stores` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`CIO Endorsed Exemption` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Financial Transparency Indicator` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Warlike Stores (Total Exemption)` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`FT CIO Endorsed Exemption` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`NAMCO funded Contract` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`PO Header Closed Code` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`PO Header Closed Date` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist EndCust7` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist EndCust8` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist NCP6` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist Prov6` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist TOW13` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist TOW14` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist TOW Other` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist Type04` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`IMP EU` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`IMP Non EU` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Security Classification` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Overseas Subcontractor` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Price Status 1 - Agreed at Outset` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Price Status 2 - tba` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Price Status 3 - Firm` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Price Status 4 - Fixed` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Price Status 5 - Provisional` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist EC Req 3` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist EC Req 4` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist EC Req 7` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist EC Req 9` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist EC Req 11` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Hist EC Req 18` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prime LOW Code` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`Prime LOW Percentage` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Prime Region` varchar(13) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prime UK-Overseas` varchar(13) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Prime LOW Payment` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`Prime LOW VAT` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`TLB Code` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`TLB Name` varchar(27) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`IMG Code` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`MG Code` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`BLB Code` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`BLB Name` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Address Line1` varchar(23) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Address Line2` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Address Line3` varchar(28) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Address Line4` varchar(22) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Address Lines Alt` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor City` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor County` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor ZIP` varchar(7) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Vendor Country` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Could you add your db table structures?

Comment: I dont see `Vendor ZIP` column. Only `Vendor Code`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: It's right at the bottom

Comment: @mike3875 Does this work, or do you get an error: `$data = $temp_table_data->setTempTable("selected_postcodes_{$timestamp_string}_{$userid}")->with('payment')->get()->toArray();`

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but consider using a proper naming convention for your db fields and methods. That will make things easier for you in the long run. Regarding the issue; like patricus says, you're trying to fetch a relation on an empty model. Btw, your reverse relation (belongsTo) will not work, as no proper table is set, Laravel will default to `temp_table` there

Comment: You should `dd()` the raw query that laravel produced and see where the query failed and adjust your code accordingly, thats what I would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue that I see is that with your given code, you've called `payment()` on an empty `TempTable` object. In order to get the related records, you first need to get the `TempTable` records. To break it down, you've done:

```
$temp_table_data = new TempTable;

// start with empty TempTable object
$payments = $temp_table_data

    // set the table attribute on the empty object
    ->setTempTable("selected_postcodes_{$timestamp_string}_{$userid}")

    // gets the payment relationship from the empty object
    ->payment()

    // gets all the payments for an empty object
    ->get()

    // converts collection to array
    ->toArray();
```

In order to get the related payments for a `TempTable` object, you first need to get the populated `TempTable` object. For example:

```
$temp_table = new TempTable;
$temp_table_data = $temp_table
    ->setTempTable("selected_postcodes_{$timestamp_string}_{$userid}")
    ->get();

// $temp_table_data is now a Collection of all the records in the given table

// loop through all the records and print out their payments
foreach($temp_table_data as $tt) {
    print_r($tt->payment->toArray());
}
```

Also note, if you wanted to speed things up a little bit, you could [eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) the payment relationships when you get the records from the temp table:

```
$temp_table_data = $temp_table
    ->setTempTable("selected_postcodes_{$timestamp_string}_{$userid}")
    ->with('payment') // eager load payment relationship
    ->get();
```

### Edit

*response to comments regarding eager loading*

In this case, since you have to set the table name after creating a new instance of the model, you can't call `with()` on the model; you need to drill down and call `with()` on a query object that is created using your instantiated model. So, instead of the code above, you need to add one more call to the method chain:

```
$temp_table_data = $temp_table
    ->setTempTable("selected_postcodes_{$timestamp_string}_{$userid}")
    ->newQuery() // get a new query builder object for this instance
    ->with('payment') // eager load payment relationship on the query object
    ->get();
```

When you call `with()` on the model, it creates a new instance of the model, and then creates a new query builder object using that new instance. The problem in your situation is that the new instance of the model will not have the table name set.

### Edit 2

*response to comments regarding selecting specific columns*

If you want to modify the query used on the payments (such as selecting only specific columns), you have two options, depending on if you're eager loading or not.

If not eager loading, you just modify the payment query like any other query:

```
foreach($temp_table_data as $tt) {
    // note the use of the relationship query (payment()), not the Collection attribute (payment)
    print_r($tt->payment()->select('Input RAC', 'Contract Number', 'Foreign Ind')->toArray());
}
```

If eager loading, you can modify the query used to eager load the data. In the `with()` method, you pass an array of relationships to eager load, where the key is the name of the relationship, and the value is a Closure used to modify the query for the relationship. One thing to note here is that if you modify the select clause, you must include the column containing the foreign key to the TempTable table, otherwise Laravel will not know how to link up the objects being created.

```
$temp_table_data = $temp_table
    ->setTempTable("selected_postcodes_{$timestamp_string}_{$userid}")
    ->newQuery() // get a new query builder object for this instance
    ->with(['payment' => function ($query) {
        // this Closure contains the query object for the payment relationship
        // make sure your select includes the foreign key
        $query->select('Vendor ZIP', 'Input RAC', 'Contract Number', 'Foreign Ind');
    }]) // eager load payment relationship on the query object
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error when trying to eager load `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used (SQL: select *)`. Do you know why?

Comment: Also, how can I use `payment` to only select certain rows from the payments table (because it's such a big table). I tried `print_r($tt->payment('Input RAC','Contract Number','Foreign Ind')->toArray());` but no luck..

Comment: @mike3875 I have updated my answer in response to your comments.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. My array has gone a little nuts. Instead of just one massive multi-array, there are lots of multi-arrays, each with a seemingly random amount of subarrays. Weird!